# Amount of data in database

Tags: sql-server, database

I know that the database can be of certain size X, but some of that file is empty, log data etc

How can I find out how much real data in B/KB/MB is in the database?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? What Database server are you using? exec sp_helpdb "Database name" using Query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx).

```
sp_spaceused [[ @objname = ] 'objname' ] 
[,[ @updateusage = ] 'updateusage' ]
```

> **[ @objname=]** *'objname'*
>
> > Is the qualified or nonqualified name of the table, indexed view, or
> >     queue for which space usage information is requested. Quotation marks
> >     are required only if a qualified object name is specified. If a fully
> >     qualified object name (including a database name) is provided, the
> >     database name must be the name of the current database.
> >
> > If objname is not specified, results are returned for the whole
> >     database.
> >
> > objname is **nvarchar(776)**, with a default of **NULL**.
>
> **[ @updateusage=]** *'updateusage'*
>
> > Indicates DBCC UPDATEUSAGE should be run to update space usage
> >     information. When *objname* is not specified, the statement is run on
> >     the whole database; otherwise, the statement is run on *objname*. Values
> >     can be true or false. updateusage is **varchar(5)**, with a default of
> >     **false**.

Comment: Perfect answer, although you could add a link to MSDN.

Comment: Happy now, Alex? :-)

Comment: Am in 7th Heaven now with the link! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can right click on your database -> Reports -> Disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to know how much of the database is pure data and how much is there to manage this data. I cannot help but wonder why you'd even want to know this, but okay...

Randolph has the right answer: [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260286(SQL.80).aspx)
I just added the link with additional information. That way, you can check how to use it, since it can also provide information about tables and other objects.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. We migrate a 8GB database at work to some external consultants. The external consultans gives us a new database containing the migrated data and ONLY the migrated data but suddenly now the database size is 40GB.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using uncompressed native backups, do a full backup to disk and check its file size - backups don't contain the free space within a database file.